# How to change color of filtered information when it is in search mode (Datatables)

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, datatables-1.10

How to change color of filtered information  when it is in search mode (Datatables)
Since it is a Datatables plugin am unable to find the exact code of only the filtered information .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`language`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) option to override text used in informational panel and use HTML markup as well.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "infoEmpty":      "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
        "infoFiltered":   "(filtered from <b>_MAX_</b> total entries)"      
     }
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/3o1kppkm/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is exactly the answer i was looking for .